# Recovery attempt for database corruption of catalog, corruption of internal tables

Tags: sql-server-2017, recovery, corruption

The issue was noticed when we ran dbbc checkdb.

**EDIT**: I looked up altering system tables and was successful in deleting
the internal table from sys.sysschobjs$ from its id.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-the-dedicated-admin-connection-to-fix-msg-8992-corrupt-system-tables/

now only one issue remains

> Msg 211, Level 23, State 245, Line 1 Corruption in database ID
> 140707423584273, object ID 60 possibly due to schema or catalog
> inconsistency. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.

**PRE FIX :**
It threw corruption error so we had moved on to do a dbcc checkcatalog of the database which resulted in

> Msg 3852, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Row (object_id=160237313) in
> sys.objects (type=IT) does not have a matching row
> (object_id=160237313,index_id=0) in sys.indexes.
>
> Msg 3852, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Row (object_id=160237313) in
> sys.objects (type=IT) does not have a matching row
> (object_id=160237313,column_id=1) in sys.columns.
>
> Msg 3857, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The attribute
> (internal_type=NULL,parent_id=NULL,parent_minor_id=NULL) is required
> but is missing for row (object_id=160237313) in sys.internal_tables.

I tried multiple things like repair-rebuild and restore with dataloss but nothing fixed this

The issue is due to

`select * from sys.internal_tables  where parent_id is null`

which results in

| name | object_id | principal_id | schema_id | parent_object_id | type | type_desc | create_date | modify_date | is_ms_shipped | is_published | is_schema_published | internal_type | internal_type_desc | parent_id | parent_minor_id | lob_data_space_id | filestream_data_space_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| queue_messages_144237256 | 160237313 | NULL | 4 | 144237256 | IT | INTERNAL_TABLE | 2023-02-25 16:07:28.660 | 2023-02-25 16:07:28.660 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0 | NULL |

Is there any way to recover this database ?

Any way to alter the system tables which this seems to be queue messages from service broker

```
dbcc checkdb repair_allow_data_loss
dbcc checkdb repair_rebuild
```

DBCC CHECKDB (DATABASE) WITH NO_INFOMSGS

> Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Check Catalog Msg 3852, State 1:
> Row (object_id=160237313) in sys.objects (type=IT) does not have a
> matching row (object_id=160237313,index_id=0) in sys.indexes.
>
> Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Check Catalog Msg 3852, State 1:
> Row (object_id=160237313) in sys.objects (type=IT) does not have a
> matching row (object_id=160237313,column_id=1) in sys.columns.
>
> Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Check Catalog Msg 3857, State 1:
> The attribute (internal_type=NULL,parent_id=NULL,parent_minor_id=NULL)
> is required but is missing for row (object_id=160237313) in
> sys.internal_tables. CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 3
> consistency errors not associated with any single object. CHECKDB
> found 0 allocation errors and 3 consistency errors in database
> 'kings'.
>
> Msg 211, Level 23, State 245, Line 1 Corruption in database ID 140707423584273, object ID 60 possibly due to schema or catalog
> inconsistency. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.
>
> Msg 211, Level 23, State 50, Line 1 Corruption in database ID 17, object ID 74 possibly due to schema or catalog inconsistency. Run DBCC
> CHECKCATALOG.

Completion time: 2023-04-26T11:10:20.5489320+05:45

Comment: What is restore with data loss,?, did you tried restoring from known good backup ? Please post complete output of the checkdb

Comment: @Shanky Known backups are later than 2 months . 
repair allow data loss I meant this...
\n

`ALTER DATABASE DbName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`

\n
`DBCC CheckDB ('DbName', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)`
\n

`ALTER DATABASE DbName SET MULTI_USER`

Comment: So when you ran checkdb with repair allow data loss it did not worked, what error came ? Also please post complete output of dbcc checkdb, add the output in question.

Comment: it told me to do dbcc checkcatalog which resulted in the above message.

Comment: Looks like a queue table that maybe should have been deleted anyway. What do you get if you do `select object_id, name from sys.service_queues`

Comment: @Charlieface it doesn't exist in sys.service_queues , I also assumed as much this is a queue entry that went wrong. The problem is mssql doesn't allow me to drop this object from its internal tables.

Comment: Try `DROP TABLE YourDb.sys.[queue_messages_144237256]` from a DAC connection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Charlieface the table didn't exist while using DAC but It was listed in internal tables so i deleted it from internal tables now only one error remains i.e. Msg 211. 
I am currently trying to recover data from a tool.

Comment: OK now you need to find which object is erroring and recreate it `select * from sys.objects where object_id = 60` try drop and recreate it

Answer (score -1):

Known option is `DBCC CheckDb (Databasename,REPAIR_REBUILD)` for such errors in system tables.
If it doesn't work or if it still shows such error, best and safest option would be to create a new database with same schema and migrate the data using **Export Data** option in SSMS or by using some third party application for data migration.

**EDIT :** I found a blog related to the issue. It suggests running sqlcmd in single user mode and deleting the orphaned queue data.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-the-dedicated-admin-connection-to-fix-msg-8992-corrupt-system-tables/

**PS :** This is a undocumented method so use this at your own risk with caution and is not recommended in production databases.

Comment: this seems like a taxing job. I will give it a try but might be open to more suggestions.

Comment: I have also stumbled on to this blog through alternate means . Some issues have been fixed . Thanks for this though. Will shortly update question.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any way to recover this database ?

Sure.  Just restore a backup.  Also your storage solution probably caused the corruption, so you may need to restore it on another server.

Comment: Database restore is impossible as the oldest backup available is of two months old.
I checked and the issue exists for that database.

Comment: Did you restore that backup to a different server that you have confidence in?

Comment: Yes I did but corruption of catalogs still occurs